# How can I pass CommandParameter into AsyncCommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, command

I want to run the button command asynchronously. The following application can run asynchronously. But I couldn't find how to pass the CommandParamater that I specified on the xaml side into the event.

What kind of application should I make? I would be glad if you help.

AsyncCommand.cs & IAsyncCommand

```
    public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
}

public class AsyncCommand : AsyncCommandBase
{
    private readonly Func<Task> _command;
    public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> command)
    {
        _command = command;
    }
    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        return _command();
    }

}
```

**AsyncCommandBase.cs**

```
    public abstract class AsyncCommandBase : IAsyncCommand
{
    public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);
    public abstract Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
   ChangePageCommand = new AsyncCommand(async () => await ChangePageClick());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would change the type of your delegate from `Func<Task>` (a method taking no parameters and returning `Task`) to `Func<object, Task>` (a method taking a single `object` parameter and returning `Task`):

```
private readonly Func<object, Task> _command;
public AsyncCommand(Func<object, Task> command) => _command = command;
public override Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter) => _command(parameter);
```